# how to a split result set into smaller sub sets?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am currently working on a project where we have to integrate the result set which I get by using oracle into mysql. Due to the restrictions of data length on their side I have to split one of the numbers in my result set into smaller pieces, which they can concatenate together.

They sent me an example code, but I have no idea how to do it in oracle.
The code looks like this:

```
Dataline := 'D' + '|' +
sc.first(OraQuery1.fields[0].AsString,50) + '|' +
sc.first(OraQuery1.fields[1].AsString,50) + '|' +
sc.first(OraQuery1.fields[2].AsString,50) + '|' +
sc.first(OraQuery1.fields[3].AsString,50) + '|' +
sc.first(OraQuery1.fields[4].AsString,50);
```

I'm not exactly sure what this code tries to accomplish, I can see that is breaks it up into smaller pieces and then concatenates them together using the delimiter, but I don't know what they are trying to tell me in the parenthesis.

If anyone can shed some light on the code or suggest ways of accomplishing this in oracle I would highly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it in the query?

```
SELECT 
   SUBSTRING(Column1, 0, 5) as Column_1, 
   SUBSTRING(Column1, 6, 10) as Column_2, 
   OtherColumn,
   AnotherColumn 
from 
   TheTable
```

However, you might look into extending or cloning the resultset. It's usually just a datastructure, or associative array or list of hashmaps you should be able to add an additional field.